# Dynamically detecting and streaming AAC using AQ's and audiofilestream

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-audio, aac

I am currently streaming MP3 and AAC radio stations.
I'm reading the ICY/HTTP headers, and when detecting audio/aac or audio/aacp in the content-type, i provide kAudioFileAAC_ADTSType as the clue for AudioFileStreamOpen, otherwise i give it kAudioFileMP3Type.

It works great, the problem is when the station is playing AAC, but doesn't send audio/aacp as content-type in the HTTP headers. When that happens, i create the audiofilestream normally with an mp3 clue (nothing is different with 0 as clue either), and then the property callbacks of the audiofilestream indicate that the stream thinks it's reading MP3, the formatList callback never happens either, and when the time comes the creation of the audio queue fails.

Is there a way to make AudioFileStream work with AAC without the AAC hint being passed in it's constructor, or does anyone has any other idea about how to detect those stations other then marking them somehow in my stations databases? I'd also rather not attempt to create a new audiofilestream with AAC as a hint each time i fail normally.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked at this code in a while, but I think it should do the trick.

```
// the file stream parser is now ready to produce audio packets.
// get the stream format.
AudioFormatListItem afli = GetFirstPlayableAudioFormatForFile(inAudioFileStream);
AudioStreamBasicDescription asbd = afli.mASBD;
...
// create the audio queue
err = AudioQueueNewOutput(&asbd, MyAudioQueueOutputCallback, myData, NULL, NULL, 0, &myData->audioQueue);
```

GetFirstPlayableAudioFormatForFile impl:

```
AudioFormatListItem GetFirstPlayableAudioFormatForFile(AudioFileStreamID inAudioFileStream)
{
    AudioFormatListItem *formatListPtr = NULL;
    AudioFormatListItem formatItem = {0};
    UInt32 propertySize;

    OSStatus status = noErr;

    if (NULL == inAudioFileStream) return formatItem;

    status = AudioFileStreamGetPropertyInfo(inAudioFileStream, kAudioFileStreamProperty_FormatList, &propertySize, NULL);
    if (noErr == status) {

        // allocate memory for the format list items
        formatListPtr = (AudioFormatListItem *)malloc(propertySize);
        if (NULL == formatListPtr) return formatItem;

        // get the list of Audio Format List Item's
        status = AudioFileStreamGetProperty(inAudioFileStream, kAudioFileStreamProperty_FormatList, &propertySize, formatListPtr);
        if (noErr == status) {
            // print out some helpful information
            UInt32 numFormats = propertySize / sizeof(AudioFormatListItem);
            printf ("This file has a %d layered data format:\n", (int)numFormats);
            /*for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numFormats; ++i) {
                CAStreamBasicDescription(formatListPtr[i].mASBD).Print();
            }*/

            UInt32 itemIndex;
            UInt32 indexSize = sizeof(itemIndex);

            // get the index number of the first playable format -- this index number will be for
            // the highest quality layer the platform is capable of playing
            status = AudioFormatGetProperty(kAudioFormatProperty_FirstPlayableFormatFromList, propertySize,
                                            formatListPtr, &indexSize, &itemIndex);
            if (noErr == status) {
                printf ("Returning AudioFormatListItem at index %d.\n", (int)itemIndex);
                // copy the format item at index we want returned
                formatItem =  formatListPtr[itemIndex];
            }
        }

        free(formatListPtr);
    } else {
        AudioStreamBasicDescription asbd;
        UInt32 asbdSize = sizeof(asbd);
        /*status = */AudioFileStreamGetProperty(inAudioFileStream, kAudioFileStreamProperty_DataFormat, &asbdSize, &asbd);
        //if (err) { errorDidOccur(myData, err, @"get kAudioFileStreamProperty_DataFormat"); return err; }

        formatItem.mASBD = asbd;
    }


    return formatItem;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response, however my problem as i said in the OP was that i do have this logic implemented already in my code, and it works sometimes. But i am not able to get the formatList property from the audiofilestream - not getting the audiofilestream property callback for it either, as long as i don't provide an AAC hint to the AudioFileStream constructor. And the hint i am only able to provide when i know i'm dealing with an AAC stream from the HTTP headers, but those aren't reliable enough, so i need another workaround to know when AudioFileStream should be created with an AAC hint

Comment: added some bounty to this one

Comment: Same problem, moreover if I pass 0 to fileFormat argument in AudioFileStreamOpen then it cannot even distinguish MP2, it determines it as MP1 and the playback goes quite fast. But if I manually pass MP2 then it works well, but for particular file.